# Bash Split by column printf output

Tags: bash, awk, split, printf, multiple-columns

For a menu, i'm trying to split the following output with a printf. 
Actually, the output is made on one column, the goal is to split the output into severals columns of 20 or 30 elements.

The text file is composed with the following items nearly 100:

```
item1
item2
item3
...
item98
item99
item100
```

Here the code. I tried with %-xxs without success.

```
LST_SRV_PSI=lst.txt
mapfile -t HOSTTAB < "$LST_SRV_PSI"
for i in ${!HOSTTAB[@]}; do
    #printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${HOSTTAB[i]}"
    printf "%3d%s) %-10s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${HOSTTAB[i]}"
done
```

I need to split this all 100 items in severals columns:

```
  1 ) ITEM1
  2 ) ITEM2
  3 ) ITEM3
  4 ) ITEM4
  5 ) ITEM5
until
 98  ) ITEM98
 99  ) ITEM99
 100 ) ITEM100
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I tried to split by columns of 20 or 30 elemens max. To got everything in the terminal

Comment: I specified it in the beginning: `The goal is to split the output into columns of 20 or 30 elements` :)

Comment: Don't use `...` in input/output. Besides shown output is still **one column per line**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other method with the loop with | column.

I share it:

```
for i in ${!HOSTTAB[@]}; do
    printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${HOSTTAB[i]}"
    echo ""
done | column
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v n=5 '{
ORS = (NR % n ? "\t" : "\n"); $1 = sprintf("%02d ) %s", NR, $1)} 1' file
```

```
01 ) item1  02 ) item2  03 ) item3  04 ) item4  05 ) item5
06 ) item6  07 ) item7  08 ) item8  09 ) item9  10 ) item10
11 ) item11 12 ) item12 13 ) item13 14 ) item14 15 ) item15
16 ) item16 17 ) item17 18 ) item18 19 ) item19 20 ) item20
21 ) item21 22 ) item22 23 ) item23 24 ) item24 25 ) item25
```

In the `awk` command, you can pass `n=20` to print 20 columns per line or `n=30` to get 30 columns per line.

Comment: Thank you for awk command. But i edit my post with the actual output which need to be split. Sorry, my post was not clear

Comment: Sorry, but i got one column

Comment: It is because your requirements are still unclear, You wrote `split the output into columns of 20 or 30 elements` in question and showed a sample output with just 1 column per line. I suggest you please review your question and edit it to make it clear.

Comment: I modified, my need is to split the actual output which is on one column to severals columns

Comment: Your awk cmd: `awk -v n=10 '{ORS = (NR % n ? "\t" : "\n")} 1' file` is interesting. But i can't display the number before item `1)`

Comment: Thanks you. is it possible to display as follow to keep an alignement: `01) ITEM1   02) ITEM2` instead of `1) ITEM1   2) ITEM2` ?

Comment: `awk -v n=10 '{ORS = (NR % n ? "\t" : "\n"); $1 = sprintf("%02d ) %s", NR, $1)} 1' file`